# How to get output values of alert box and send it to another html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with my system. It's a normal e-commerce system using checkboxes to add the selected products to the buyer's inventory. To get the result receipt, I used an alert box to display what products did the buyer bought based on the checkbox  they checked. So I used a switch case statement on the method, varying the alert box's result on what they bought.

It works and all, it displays the product, price and quantity along with the total price. But now I want to print the receipt (which is the alert box) however when I used the window.print() it doesn't print the contents of the alert box, instead it prints the html page.

Now, I figured that I could just create another html and set the windows.location to that html when the confirm() confirmation is true. Then once I'm on that page, I want to figure out how to get the values from the switch case and set it there. Sort of like copy pasting the result of the alert box to that new html page.

I have this Javascript to display the receipt in alert :

```
function checkout()
{
    var message = "";

    var checkboxes  = document.forms["theForm"].elements["checkbox"];
    var quants      = document.forms["theForm"].elements["quantity"];
    var name = document.forms["theForm"].elements["item"].value;

    message += "                  Your Receipt" + " \n" + "\n";


    var arr = [];
    var fieldNames2=["Bloodborne ", "GTA ", "Fallout ", "NBA "];

    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)  
    if (checkboxes[i].checked){
    arr += "Price: $" + Number(checkboxes[i].value) * Number(quants[i].value)+ "          " + "Quantity:   " + Number(quants[i].value) + "      Product: " + fieldNames2[i] + "\n"; 
    }

    var r = confirm(message + arr + "\nTotal:   " + document.getElementById("totalDiv").firstChild.data);
    if (r == true) {
    window.location = 'receipt.php';
    } else {
    window.location = 'PS4.php';
    }     
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried a lot of things?

Comment: Yes, lots and lots of things. I just want the output of the alert to be copy pasted to another html form when the user clicks on the ok button on the alert message.

Comment: So please add you code, also check if localstorage might help you in anyway.